# Custom Adapter not allowed in interface for Listener I'm creating?

Tags: java, android, listener

I'm trying to create an onWeekChangesListener for my calendar app, to display  events only for that week and when you swipe to the next week, it will change to those events. I have successfully done this for the OnMonthChanges the difference is that the listener was already created for the months. I created a new interface for the onWeekChangesListener, but when I go to use my adapter it says: not allowed in interface.

This is my interface code the mExampleAdapter lines at the bottom give me errors are mExampleAdapter is in red, if I try to add

```
ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
```

like I've done in the MainActivity it all turns red without much help from android-studio.

```
    void onWeekChanges(
            MaterialCalendarView widget,
            CalendarDay calendarDay);
    {

        View view = null;
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.reclycer_view);
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        Date d1 = new Date();
        c.setTime(d1);
        int week = c.WEEK_OF_YEAR;
        DateTime firstD = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(week);
        DateTime endD = new DateTime().withWeekOfWeekyear(week + 1);

        String firstDate = firstD + " 00:00:00";
        String endDate = endD + " 23:00:00";

        List<Events> listado = SQLite.select().from(Events.class)
                .where(Events_Table.end_date.greaterThanOrEq(firstDate))
                .and(Events_Table.init_date.lessThanOrEq(endDate))
                .queryList();

        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(listado);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);
    }
}
```

my Example Adapter below

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {

    private List<Events> mEvents;
    private Funtions funt;

    public ExampleAdapter(List<Events> exampleList) {
        mEvents = exampleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, null, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Events currentItem = mEvents.get(position);

        //if its a one day event will only display that day
        //and if not will display the range like this X - X
        int iDate = Integer.parseInt(funt.formatDateToDay(currentItem.init_date));
        int eDate = Integer.parseInt(funt.formatDateToDay(currentItem.end_date));

        if (iDate == eDate) {
            holder.mTextViewDate.setText(funt.formatDateToDay(currentItem.init_date));
            holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(currentItem.title);
        } else {
            holder.mTextViewDate.setText
                    (funt.formatDateToDay(currentItem.init_date) + " - " + funt.formatDateToDay(currentItem.end_date));
            holder.mTextViewTitle.setText(currentItem.title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEvents.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTextViewDate, mTextViewTitle;

        public ExampleViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTextViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_date);
            mTextViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your interface too,and full class of ExampleAdapter so can check in details